# C++, идиома Opaque Pointer и паттерн Стратегия

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли в `C++` следующее:

**something.cpp:**

```
#include <memory>
// Base - полный тип.
#include "Base.hpp"    

std::unique_ptr<Base> create_derived()
{
    // Derived - неполный тип, наследник класса Base.
    class Derived;
    return std::make_unique<Derived>();
}
```

Я хочу сконструировать `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` и вернуть это в виде `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. При этом, я бы не хотел включать заголовочный файл с полным описанием типа `Derived` в единицу трансляции `something.cpp`.

Но я получаю от компилятора сообщение примерно следующего содержания:

```
Отсутствует оператор =, соответствующий этим операндам: std::unique_ptr<Base> = std::unique_ptr<Derived>.
```

Я так полагаю, это происходит из-за того, что в данном случае тип `Derived` является неполным?

Comment: Непонятно, при чем тут opaque pointer, стратегия или pimpl, но код нерабочий, это да. Как вы вообще собирались создавать экземпляр класса `Derived`, если он не определен? А `std::unique_ptr` c удалятором по-умолчанию требует, чтобы класс был определен в момент вызова деструктора. Так что сделать даже пустой `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это невозможно по двум причинам,

1) Присваивание `std::unique_ptr<Base>` значения `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` невозможно без полного определения Derived, т.к. надо убедиться что Derived это наследник Base.

Об этом и говорит сообщение компилятора.

2) `std::make_unique<Derived>()` делает `new Derived()`, а это невозможно без полного определения Derived, т.к. должен быть виден конструктор по-умолчанию.